# Alinear los datos de las celdas en una tabla de Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table

Estoy creando una tabla en Reactjs con los datos que tengo guardado en Firebase.
Necesito que mi tabla se muestre asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y solo he podido lograr esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo evitar que las celdas se ajusten asi de esa manera, yo no quiero que esten del mismo tamaño sino que cada fila se acomode de acuerdo a la cantidad de datos que tenga. Si alguien tiene una idea y me puede ayudar o sugerir, Aqui dejo mas informacion de lo que tengo:

El objeto de Firebase esta estructurado de la siguiente forma:

```
   idReport: 1,
   fechaReport: 1672095031879,
   nombreReport: Reporte de ventasKey y nroPedido,
   filas: {
     fila1: {
       campo: "ventasKey",
       filtro: [101000003599, 101000003600, 101000003601, 101000003602, 101000003603, 101000003604, 101000003605,101000003606, 101000003607, 101000003608, 101000003609, 101000003610],
     },
     fila2: {
       campo: "nroPedido",
       filtro: [0010028160, 0010028161, 0010028163, 0010028164, 0010028165],
     },
     fila3: {
       campo: "codDirEntrega",
       filtro: [01,02,03],
     },
     fila4: {
       campo: "",
       filtro: [],
     },
     fila5: {
       campo: "",
       filtro: [],
     }
   },
   columnas: {
     columna1: {
       campo: "proveedor",
       filtro: ["A & S Negocios e Inversiones S.A.C", "Daryza S.A.C"],
     }
   },
   valores: {
     valor1: {
       campo: "soles"
     },
     valor2: {
       campo: "totalSoles",
     },
     valor3: {
       campo: "Cantidad",
     },
     valor4: {
       campo: "",
     },
     valor5: {
       campo: "",
     }
   }
```

Este es el codigo donde pinto mi tabla:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getLastDocumentOfTheCollection } from "../Firebase/firebase.config";

const Report = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  console.log(data, "data");

  useEffect(() => {
    getLastDocumentOfTheCollection(setData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="table-wrapper">
      <h5>{data?.nombreReport}</h5>
      <table className="containerTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>{data?.filas?.fila1.campo}</th>
            <th className={data?.filas?.fila2.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila2.campo}
            </th>
            <th className={data?.filas?.fila3.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila3.campo}
            </th>
            <th className={data?.filas?.fila4.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila4.campo}
            </th>
            <th className={data?.filas?.fila5.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila5.campo}
            </th>
            {data?.columnas?.columna1.filtro.map((columns, i) => {
              return columns === "" ? (
                <th key={i}></th>
              ) : (
                <th key={i}>{columns}</th>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              {data?.filas?.fila1.filtro.map((rows, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>{rows}</tr>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td className={data?.filas?.fila2.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila2.filtro.map((rows2, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>{rows2}</tr>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td className={data?.filas?.fila3.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila3.filtro.map((rows3, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>{rows3}</tr>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td className={data?.filas?.fila4.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila4.filtro.map((rows4, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>{rows4}</tr>
              ))}
            </td>
            <td className={data?.filas?.fila5.campo === "" ? "hide" : ""}>
              {data?.filas?.fila5.filtro.map((rows5, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>{rows5}</tr>
              ))}
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Report;
```

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en como armas el body de la tabla. Vos tenes un único ``<tr>`` (table row, es decir, una fila) para todos los datos. Entiendo que por cada conjunto de datos deberias crear una unica row, y ahi colocar cada ``<td>`` para que se corresponda con el valor de su columna (``<th>``)

Comment: con "sino que cada fila se acomode de acuerdo a la cantidad de datos que tenga" ¿te refieres a que quieres que los registros que tienen datos en las 5 columnas vayan primero, los de 4 después de las de 5 y así sucesivamente?

Comment: @AlexVarela no me refiero a eso, cada fila puede tener n cantidad de datos, solo necesito que se alineen uno debajo del otro no asi como se ven ahorita centrados en el contenedor...

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con uno debajo del otro, ¿será que puedes ejemplificarlo en una tabla de excel?

Comment: @AlexVarela en la misma pregunta puse una imagen de la tabla que necesito hacer, como esa primera imagen necesito que se vean mis datos. En la segunda imagen es lo que he podido hacer

Comment: Ese es el asunto, no veo la diferencia jeje, ¿puedes señalarlo? La unica diferencia que noto es que los headers están en el centro en lugar de a la izquierda y que no tienes bordes. También veo que en el excel el pedido ...60 le corresponde a la llave ...99 mientras que en tu tabla, tienes que la orden ...60 pertence a ...02... ¿Es esto lo que tratas de resolver?

Comment: Hola *@Naidamag*, Gracias por tu pregunta. Una consulta, el objeto de firebase podrías cambiar la estructura JSON?. De tal forma puedas tener un objeto con dos array, uno con los encabezados y el otro con los valores de cada celda. Asi sea mas facil construirlo en react

Comment: Por otro lado @Naidamag, No es buan practica y no es correcto a nivel de semántica HTML insertar un <tr> dentro un tag <td> . Si corres un validar HTML te señalara esos errores. Y mas si usas SEO.